# Problem with settings for using Internet on Ubuntu

Tags: internet, ubuntu-10.04, networkmanager, broadband

I am a student and using **Ubuntu 10.04 and Windows 7 as dual boot**.

In my college, we have a **proxy server**, so all I need to use the internet is set the proxy settings in `Preferences -> Network Proxy` and I am set to go.

At my home, I have a **broadband connection** that requires me to enter my username and password and then its all set on Windows. However, I have no idea how to get it right with Ubuntu.

Once I tried doing that by setting the **PPPOE settings** and then it worked on Ubuntu too, but when I came back to college, the internet stopped working.

All I remember is that I did some stuff with setting some `Network Manager` stuff to `false` or something like that, and it continued working with the proxy server too.

Please help me with this, so that I can easily use internet both at home and college too.

Comment: They have a proxy server that blocks the whole internet? Or are you trying to access a site that they block?

Comment: The problem is not with the proxy server, i can use internet with it. I mentioned it just to describe the use case scenarios(in this case 2: 1st proxy server and 2nd PPPoE broadband). I want to know how to can I easily use both when I wish to.